# Unable to pass variable to a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have this `_index` partial for comments that I want to display under pictures `show` page.

I am rendering the partial in my media view currently like this:

```
<div id="comments">
    <%= render partial: 'comments/index'  %>
</div>
```

My comments controller looks like this:

```
def index
        @comments = Comment.all
        render partial: 'comments/index', locals: { :comments => @comments }
end
```

And the coffescript code that I use to reload it looks like this:

```
setInterval (=> $('#comments').load('/comments')), 1000
```

Now in my view when I try to access the :comments variable that I sent to the partial, I am unable to do it. It contains no values.

How can I get the values properly to that partial?

Worth noting that the instance variable `@comments` is also not accessible from my partial.

Comment: Since you aren't doing anything clever with the `@comments` object why not just use `Comment.all` inside your partial instead? You should really be able to access the `@comments` object though, so something must be going awry.

Comment: It's basically saying that my @comments is nil. Currently I am indeed taking all the comments from Model in my view, but I would really like to leave that task to my controller not the view. If it helps, the index partial is rendered into another view that belongs to another controller called media_controller. Maybe that causes the problem?

Comment: Ah, actually, on the first page load, the @comments does not have a value, but when it's reloaded by my coffescript, then it does. But still this is a problem. I am rendering the same partial and on the inital render, it does not have the info I passed to it.

Comment: why are you rendering a partial instead of the standard `index.html.erb`?

Comment: Well because the ´index.html.erb´ has to be inside of another page. According to my knowledge I can only do this with a partial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're rendering the comments `index` partial from the picture `show` view.

The action in use here is `picture show`. When rendering the comments partial it will *not* call the comments controller. That's why the `@comments` variable isn't accessible.

So instead define the `@comments` in your **picture controller**

```
def show
  @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
  @comments = @picture.comments
end
```

Then pass them from the **picture/show view** to your partial

```
<div id="comments">
  <%= render partial: 'comments/index', :locals => :comments => @comments  %>
</div>
```

Comment: But now what if I want to update just the partial like every 10 seconds to see new comments. I update the picture controllers show?

Comment: I'd suggest you check this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/229-polling-for-changes. You basically perform an AJAX request every x seconds on the `comments index` action. StackOverflow use `Sockets`, a more modern approach, but I have no idea how that works :)

Comment: StackOverflow is also written in Rails?! Also, thank you for the answer, I will look into the link also.

Comment: Nope (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10372/is-stackoverflow-com-written-in-ruby-on-rails), but `Sockets` can be used in Rails as well. But I first have to look into it. And glad to help!